# sed command to replace all the occurences of js in a html files

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, sed

I have a bunch of html files from which I need to replace all the occurences of js(which are currently blocked by Jenkins) with a new js path.

For ex: in a folder called `www` i have some bunch of html files
instance take index.html has many references of `src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>` I need to replace this lines with `src=https://<some-jenkins-server>/userContent/bootstrap.min.css`

I should be able to replace all the JS from a bunch of html files from a folder using a loop with a sed command

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for htmlfile in *.html; do
    sed -i "s/\(.*src=['\"]\)[^'\"]*\.js\(['\"].*\)/\1https:\/\/<some-jenkins-server>\/userContent\/bootstrap.min.css\2/g" $htmlfile
done
```

**explanation**

```
for htmlfile in *.html; do      # loop over all *.html files
   ...
done


sed -i "              # start sed with option inplace
s/                    # substitution
\(.*src=['\"]\)       # store everything up to ' or " in arg1
[^'\"]*\.js           # the javascript
\(['\"].*\)           # store everything up to end of line in arg2
/\1                   # write arg1
https:\/\/<some-jenkins-server>\/userContent\/bootstrap.min.css  # write replacement
\2                    # write arg2
/g"                   # global on whole line
$htmlfile             # inputfile
```

If your sed version does not have an option inplace (-i), then you need to redirect the output to a file.